# How to put multiple JsonObject inside JsonArray using volley library?

Tags: android, android-json

How to put arrayList in jsonArray on server side?

try to put parameter
  "list": [
    {
      "year": "2019",
      "amt": 6222
    },
    {
      "year": "2016",
      "amt": 5555
    }
  ]}

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work :

```
JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

try {
    jsonObject1.put("year", "2019");
    jsonObject1.put("amt", "6222");
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject1);
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();

    jsonObject2.put("year", "2016");
    jsonObject2.put("amt", "5555");
    jsonArray.put(jsonObject2);

    JSONObject jsonObjectList = new JSONObject();
    jsonObjectList.put("list",jsonArray);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The result will be:

```
{"list":[{"year":"2019","amt":"6222"},{"year":"2016","amt":"5555"}]}
```

Comment: @Thanks for help, but there is multiple jsonObject put inside jsonArray. How its possible? mean JsonObject not fix value put on server side..

Comment: @There is multiple jsonObject put

Comment: @DevanandAdabaile you can use List<Model> to get size of your List (Multiple jsonObject)
and set a loop to get size of List<Model>

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem solution, try this

```
  JSONArray jsonArray =  new JSONArray();
       for (int i =0; i < ItemModelList.size(); i++){
         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
         jsonObject.put("year", String.valueOf(ItemModelList.get(i).getYear()));
         jsonObject.put("amt", String.valueOf(ItemModelList.get(i).getAmount()));
         jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
         requestJson.put("list", jsonArray);
       }

Result:
 "list": [ { "year": "2019", "amt": 6222 }, { "year": "2016", "amt": 5555 } ]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.